# SQL query and computing resources, how to use another computer?

Tags: database, sql-server, sql

I have a SQL System from a company. This system automatically updates its database every night from the production system. I can run SQL queries on a GUI and get results.

But I have one query searching in a table xreferences. When executing this query the gui hangs up and if I let it run over night the nightly update does not happen.

The programming company was asked and they ran this query on a snapshot. They said, this query runs fine within 5 minutes and it could be a resource (RAM) problem on the SQL server.

When I run a SQL query the resources of the computer where the SQL database is installed are used, correct?

Is it possible to use the resources of another computer? Is this possible without copying the database onto this computer?

Comment: Many things are not making sense. SQL System? There is a database that is on a server. SQL has nothing to do with that. The "GUI" is a program, that uses graphical user interfacing. So to me it seems that if you use the program it's fine, but if you don't use the program it's not? The program most likely has credentials that logs into the database, but it's happening "under the hood". It's likely that you need to get log in credentials from the Administrator of the company. You work there? If you aren't an employee of "the company", then that would be the problem I think. Reword the question?

Comment: You would need to check either end. Check your system usage during the query and the system usage on the server. You won't be able to use the resources of another computer for the server (easily). But you might be able to make your query more efficient.